# Clang-format setting for aligning operator+=, operator-=, etc

Tags: c++, operators, clang-format

Setting `AlignConsecutiveAssignments: true` in `.clang-format` aligns `=`, i.e.

```cpp
 int a   = 0;
 int bcd = 0;
 int ef  = 0;
```

But is there a similar setting to also align other operators like `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=`, etc., i.e.

```cpp
 a    = 1;
 bcd += 2;
 ef  -= 3;
```

?

Comment: Unfortunately, `clang-format` doesn't support this currently.